# Intellij suppress warnings

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to suppress an instance of a warning in my code. I use the intellij feature alt-enter to add the suppress warning annotation to the method, also tried with the class. But whenever I hit the rebuild button, the warning keeps coming up as if the suppress warning annotation isn't being recognised.

I've read a few answers that suggest disable completely, or you can suppress individual entry using this notation. I know I can disable it completely through settings, but I'd rather just suppress this instance. Does anyone know why it wouldn't be suppressing the warning?

```
Information:Using Eclipse compiler to compile java sources
Information:Compilation completed successfully with 1 warning in 9 sec
Information:0 errors
Information:1 warning
...TagValidator.java
Warning:(41, 16) java: Type safety: Unchecked cast from java.lang.Object to java.util.List<common.model.Tag>
```

Method in question:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        logger.entry();

        List<Tag> list;

        list = (List<Tag>) target;

        for (Tag tag : list) {
            if (tag.getTag().length() > 30) {
                errors.rejectValue("tags", "tags.length");
                break;
            }

        }
        logger.exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the eclipse (`ejc`) compiler. When the `javac` compiler is used, no warnings are present upon make/compilation. But if you switch to the eclipse compiler, then you get the warnings. In the (closed) IntelliJ IDEA bug report [ecj doesn't use @SuppressWarnings](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121772) the JetBrains development team indicated that

> IDEA uses such suppressions for its own error highlighting, which is compiler-independent. Similarly, it runs external compiler as is, without any interference.

So IDEA isn't doing anything to tell ejc not to use/honor the `SuppressWarnings` annotations.

Comment: ah ok no worries, so it's just a bug. Thanks.